# How can I make a junction point or symlink point to a different place for different users?

Tags: windows, junction

Example scenario: I want `c:\temp` to point to each user's temp directory, even if multiple users are logged in simultaneously.

I can run code during user logon, e.g., using a logon script, the Run key, etc., but it must work for non-administrative users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for the [local DOS devices namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554302%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)!

During user logon, create a device name pointing to the temporary folder:

```
DefineDosDevice(DDD_RAW_TARGET_PATH, L"TempFolder", L"\??\C:\<path>");
```

You can then log on as an administrative user and create the junction point or symlink.  For example:

```
mklink /J c:\temp \\?\TempFolder
```

A few notes:

- You cannot create a junction point to a device name that does not both exist in the current logon session and point to a local drive.  So make sure you create the device name before attempting to create the junction point.  (This does not apply to symlinks.)
- If UAC is enabled, administrators will have two logon sessions, one elevated and one restricted.  If you want the link to work in both sessions you must create the device name in both sessions.
- The device name path should not include a trailing backslash.
- You cannot prevent the user from redefining where the folder points to in their own logon session.  So this cannot be part of a security mechanism.
- If the file system is being backed up, you should test whether the presence of such a junction point / symlink breaks the backup software.  Most backup software does not attempt to follow junction points or symlinks, so it should usually be OK.  (However, a restore operation for the junction point or symlink may fail if the device name does not exist.)
- As near as I can tell, the only reason I need to use the `\\?\` format (rather than `\??\`) when creating the junction point is that the `mklink` command misinterprets the latter as a relative path.  If you are creating the junction point in code, you can probably use either.  For more context, see also ["Path prefixes \??\ and \?\"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28821145).
- The local DOS device namespace appears to be per-remote-desktop-session as well as per-logon-session.  Under normal circumstances this won't matter, but I'm not sure what will happen if you're doing weird stuff like explicitly changing a token's remote desktop session.

Comment: To elaborate on the 2nd note, in the root NT namespace, `\DosDevices` is a link to `\??`, which for a non-system thread expands to the logon-session DOS devices directory in `\Sessions\0\DosDevices\[LOGONID]`. Within that directory there's a `Global` link back to the `\Global??` DOS devices directory. So for a UAC elevated logon session `\??` maps to a different directory, which is why if you `subst` a drive in an elevated command prompt it won't appear in a non-elevated instance of Explorer.

Comment: @eryksun: yep. That's exactly the same magic that makes it work in the first place; each user sees the TempFolder they set in their own DosDevices directory.  The key point about UAC is that you get two logon sessions rather than just one; it has never been obvious to me exactly why, though presumably it has to do with providing a greater level of isolation between the two tokens.  IIRC, the documentation only ever talks about there being two tokens, not mentioning that there are also two logon sessions.

Comment: There has to be separate tokens since the two security contexts have to coexist. The 2nd DOS devices directory is a natural consequence of there being two separate logons. I doubt whether it adds much to security to isolate the DOS devices like this. It's just annoying. I wish they'd instead made it a symbolic link to the non-elevated logon's DOS devices directory.

Comment: @eryksun: the CreateRestrictedToken function already creates a new token based on an existing one, so there's no inherent need for a second logon to get the second token.  IIRC, when I looked at the sequence of events when an admin logged on under UAC, there were two logons, creating two separate tokens, and then a third token was created, presumably using CreateRestrictedToken or a native equivalent, and the corresponding original token discarded.  (And yes, very annoying; there was a hotfix that corrected this available at one point, but I think it's gone.)

Comment: I had half of the problem in my brain without thinking through the consequences. DOS devices were broken out into logon sessions instead of terminal-services sessions because mapped network drives can depend on credentials (single sign-on) from a particular logon session. So using a symbolic link wouldn't work.